# matlab how to replace a number in the list by its nearest neighbour

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a long list (array) in matlab.

```
              -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2
```

I want to replace the -1 s by its nearest positive values.

```
               1, 1,  1,  1,  1, 1, 1, 2,  2,  2, 2
```

What is the effective way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to *replace the negative values with the nearest non-negative values*.

This can be done with [`interp1`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with the `'nearest'` and `'extrap'` options (thanks to @rayryeng for the latter):

```
x = [1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 2, 2, 2];
ind = x<0;
xi = interp1(find(~ind),x(~ind),find(ind),'nearest','extrap');
x(ind) = xi;
```

Comment: Actually I was trying this, just wasn't able to figure out the syntax! :

Comment: Thanks, But I am getting NaN at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @user570593 - Use the `extrap` flag.

Comment: @LuisMendo - My pleasure :) I had to use `interp1` for something I was working on recently, and I needed to enable extrapolation in order to get the logic to work. The `extrap` flag is very handy.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `A` to be the input array, you can use a **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** + **[`min`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html)** based approach -

```
%// Locations of A with -1 and positive valued locations
p1 = find(A==-1)
p2 = find(A>=0)

%// Find the indices of minimum distance locations for each element 
%// with -1 to the closest positive valued elements
[~,min_idx] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,p1(:).',p2(:))),[],1) %//'
%// OR [~,min_idx] = min(pdist2(p1(:),p2(:)),[],2)

%// Set -1 valued A's elements with elements located at min_idx 
%// in positive valued array
A(p1) = A(p2(min_idx))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting an error 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions'.  at p2(min_idx).

Comment: @user570593 Could you check what's the value of `min_idx` for that error?

Comment: some values in min_idx is higher than the length of p2.

Comment: @user570593 Are you sure you have copied and pasted the code as it is. It's working at my end. There is a transpose on `p2` in  `bsxfun(@minus,p1,p2')`.

Comment: yes. I copied it correct. But my original list is a very long one. Not the one I posted here.

Comment: @user570593 Is the input array a 1D array or 2D array or something else?

Comment: @user570593 Ah! Figured out! Your input is a column vector it seems. Made few changes in the codes. Check out the edits please!